# Divisors of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Please hint me. I have a question in my homework. let $n\in\mathbf{N}$ and $a$ and $b$ are two nontrivial divisors of $n$, so that $a\nmid b$ and $b\nmid a$ and $a>b$.  I want to prove that  there is at least one $d\mid n$, so that $b\mid d$ but $a\nmid d$. for example:

> $n=432$ and $a=18, b=12$, then there are $24,48$ divisors of $432$ so that $12\mid 24,48$ but $18\nmid 24,48$.

thanks in advance 
I proof my question in the following manner:

Let $\left[\dfrac{a}{b}\right]=r$, put $d=(r-1)b$, clearly $b\mid d$ and $a\nmid d$, if $a\mid d$ then $d=ka=(r-1)b$, so $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{r-1}{k}<r$ is contradiction because $r\leq\dfrac{a}{b}<r$.
my proof is hold when $r>1$, if $r=1$?

Comment: Does $d=b$ work?

Comment: Otherwise we could take $n=6$, $a=3$, $b=2$, and there is no solution.

Comment: To make it non-trivial ($d = b$), maybe we can add the condition $\gcd(a,b) \ne 1$ and then require $d \ne b$.

Comment: @M.Vinay ah yes, that would make a more interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

So $n$ is composite and $a$ and $b$ are nontrivial divisors of $n$, right? I could be wrong, but it looks to me like $n$ can't be the square of a prime, nor any perfect power of a prime, for that matter.

So, if $n$ is a squarefree semiprime, you can just do $d = b$, like Peter suggests. This may seem cheap or cheesy, but unless you neglected to mention some condition that disallows such an easy answer, it is perfectly valid.

But $n$ can have perfect powers of primes among its divisors, which gives you more choices. Say $n = b^4 a^3$, then $d = b^2$ meets the requirements, right?